# NoMethodError and failure/error in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

The following is my search method from the controller

```
@accounts = []
    client = GameAccounts::GameAccountsClient.new



    if params[:name]


      # Try and find a game account by id using the given name
      response = client.get_accounts_by_name(params[:name])

      if response.is_a?(Net::HTTPSuccess)
        account = client.parse_json(response)
        unless account.empty?
          session[:account] = account
          redirect_to game_account_path(params[:name])
        end
      end

      json = client.get_json(params[:limit],params[:offset],params[:name])

      @presenter = GameAccountsPresenter.new(json)

    end
  end
```

I am trying to run the following test :

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe GameAccountsController do
  describe 'GET search' do
    it 'finds a named system account directly' do
     get(:search, name: 'test').to be_redirect_to(game_account_path('test'))
    end
  end
end
```

I keep getting a

```
GameAccountsController GET search finds a named system account directly
     Failure/Error: get(:search, name: 'test').to be_redirect_to(game_account_path('test'))
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `to' for #<ActionController::TestResponse:0x007f8b0beb3e10>
     # ./spec/controllers/game_accounts_controller_spec.rb:6:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

can anyone please let me know what i am doing wrong ?? .. tried doing .should redirect_to and i still get the same error but with method 'should'.

Answer (score 1):

From this documentation, it looks like your code should be a little more like this:

```
it 'finds a named system account directly' do
  get(:search, name: 'test')
  expect(response).to be_redirect_to(game_account_path('test'))
end
```

Source:
https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails#controller-specs

Comment: Right now, all i can come up with is a possible bug in the version of rspec you are using. What version are you using?

Comment: gem "rspec-rails", '~> 2.12'.....Also when i try doing a get index and checking if the response is a success ..it takes forever when i run rake and system tends to get slow